# Media Queries para identificar notch

Tags: css, css3, scss

Alguém tem uma solução completa para identificar todos os celulares que possuem o tal do "notch" nas versões existentes do mercado? Atualmente eu estou utilizando esses estratégias, mas ainda estou tendo problema com algumas versões de celulares que não possuem notch, porém são identificados como se tivessem:

```
$margin_max_constant_notch:unquote('max(-12px, constant(safe-area-inset-left))');
$margin_max_env_notch:unquote('max(-12px, env(safe-area-inset-left))');


/*** iphone X 1.11, iphone XS (obs: ',' é representação de OR) ***/
@media only screen
and (device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 812px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3),
 /*** iphone XR ***/
screen and (device-width : 414px)
and (device-height : 896px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2),
  /*** iphone XS Max ***/
screen and (device-width : 414px)
and (device-height : 896px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3),
  /*** iphone XS Max Retina ***/
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 458dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 3dppx),
/** Google Pixel 3 XL  **/
screen and (device-width: 360px)
and (device-height: 740px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 4/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 4),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 523dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 4dppx) {

    @media(orientation: portrait) {

       //celular na vertical

       //global CSS

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
         //até 768px
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {
         //até 480px
        }

       @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
           //até 400px
        }


    }
    @media(orientation: landscape) {
        html,body {
            padding: $margin_max_constant_notch;
            padding: $margin_max_env_notch;
        }

        //celular na horizontal

        @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

          //até 900px
        }

    }
}

/** iphone X 1.12 **/
@supports(padding: max(0px)) {
@media screen and (device-width : 375px)
and (device-height : 812px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) {
    @media(orientation: portrait) {

       //celular na vertical

        @media (max-width: 768px) {
           //até 768px
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {
         //até 480px
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        //até 400px
        }

      }
      @media(orientation: landscape) {
        html, body {
          padding: $margin_max_constant_notch;
          padding: $margin_max_env_notch;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
         //até 900px
        }
      }
   }
}

/** iphone 8 **/
@media only screen
and (device-width : 375px)
and (device-height : 667px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2),
  /** iphone 8 PLUS **/
screen  and (device-width : 414px)
and (device-height : 736px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) {
  @media(orientation: portrait) {

  //celular na vertical

  }
  @media(orientation: landscape) {

  //celular na horizontal
  }
}

@media only screen
  /** IPADS **/
and (min-device-width: 1024px)
and (max-device-width: 1366px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

 //para ipads

  @media(orientation: portrait) {

  //ipad na vertical

  }
  @media(orientation: landscape) {

  //ipad na horizontal
  }

}
```